# Can i autoscale DMS Replication instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I Have created DMS with replication instance and mysql to mysql endpoints. My replication instance will be running 24*7.

I will run run mysql to mysql tasks frequently on it. But the size of data will always be varying. I want my DMS to be comfortable with all data sizes.

Can i setup replication instance to perform autoscaling on the basis of data size?

Is either horizontal or vertical scaling possible in DMS ???

Answer (score 1):

You can scale based on the metrics DMS provides but it would require setting up some additional things like cloudwatch alarms, sns, and lambda. They have a tutorial on how to achieve this: [How to Scale AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) replication instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-scale-aws-database-migration-service-dms-replication-instances/).
[image]